# Why using Atomic here?

Tags: java, spring, java.util.concurrent

While reading the source code of SpringRetry, I come across this code snippet:

```
private static class AnnotationMethodsResolver {

    private Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType;

    public AnnotationMethodsResolver(Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType) {
        this.annotationType = annotationType;
    }

    public boolean hasAnnotatedMethods(Class<?> clazz) {
        final AtomicBoolean found = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(clazz,
                new MethodCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void doWith(Method method) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                            IllegalAccessException {
                        if (found.get()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        Annotation annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method,
                                annotationType);
                        if (annotation != null) { found.set(true); }
                    }
        });
        return found.get();
    }

}
```

My question is, why using `AtomicBoolean` as a local variable here? I have checked the source code of `RelfectionUtils.doWithMethods()` and didn't find any concurrency invocation there.

Comment: Well concurrency is one of the reasons you would use something like `AtomicBoolean`, so maybe you should check again.

Comment: Sorry I really can not find any concurrency in org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods,

Comment: You need to find uses of this class, and see if this object is ever held in a multithreaded context.

Comment: the variable "found" is a local variable, as far as i know it is safe for "found" to use the method "hasAnnotatedMethods" in a multithreaded context

Comment: You are missing the point.  There is probably some context where an instance of `AnnotationMethodsResolver` is being used by multiple threads.  So your search needs to focus on this, not just on reflection utils.

Comment: "found" is a local variable, and "Local variables are thread safe in Java." calling the method of AnnotationMethodResolver in a multithreaded context will not have any issue with local variable "found" as per my knowledge

Comment: I found the reason, I forgot the rule "the local variable accessed by inner class should be declared as final".....anyway, thanks for the comment. have a nice day!

Comment: The anonymous class might explain `final`, but does it explain why an atomic variable is being used?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen AtomicBoolean could just be to make a mutable boolean (that can still be `final`). Useful even in single-threaded scenarios.

Comment: maybe they think using atmoic instead of a boolean array is more fancy here :) the compiler will not complain if you are using atomic variable without final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each invocation of `hasAnnotatedMethods` gets its own instance of `found`, so the context from which `hasAnnotatedMethods` is called doesn't matter.

It is *possible* that `ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods` calls the `doWith` method from multiple threads, which would require `doWith` to be thread safe.

I suspect that `AtomicBoolean` is just being used to return a value from the callback, and that `boolean[] found = new boolean[1];` would do just as well.

Comment: yeah, i think so, but i cannot find any concurrency in ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods. I just realized the rule that "found" should be decalred as final when it is accessed by a inner class. but i still can not understand why there is a "if (found.get()) " right in the doWith method

Comment: The `if(found.get())` is there to short-circuit, because `doWithMethods` will loop over all methods, but you can stop as soon as you have found one. It won't stop the looping, but the later iterations will just be empty.